# Смена цвета statusBara

Tags: android, themes

Родительская тема - Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. Если указываю colorPrimary серым, а colorPrimaryDark любым цветным - все прекрасно работает. Панель задач и строка состояния разного цвета. Но если colorPrimaryDark указываю темнее, то строка состояния и панель задач сливается в цвет colorPrimary.

Пробовала разные способы решения. Прописать ststusBarColor не помогло. Вылетает приложение. Сделать родительским CoordinatorLayout тоже не решило проблему.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_white_36dp"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
<resources>
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkLight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentLight</item>

</style>


<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте стили для ваших аппбара и тулбара, после этого не должно быть проблем.

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

И задайте их для апп бара и тулбара

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```